# Can I use a 24v passive PoE-Injector to power my EAP650 which supports 48v passive PoE?

Tags: networking, power-over-ethernet, ubiquiti, unifi

My intention was to power my TP Link EAP650 which supports 48v passive PoE with a unifi 24v PoE Injector. Would that work?

Comment: You need to determine from documentation the voltage range of the 48 volt unit. If spec'd for 48 volts, 24 volts will be too underpowered.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no, as John indicated the 24v that your injector provides would not provide enough power for the AP to function properly.

I was hoping there might be a workaround, I found a splitter (https://shop.poetexas.com/products/gaf-12v12w) that would convert the 24V to a 12V barrel adapter. Even if the barrel adapter fits though, the splitter I found could only provide up to 1 amp, and the EAP650 power supply provides 1.5 amps (https://www.reddit.com/r/TPLink_Omada/comments/15th334/which_power_supply_for_eap650/), so there's a good chance if the AP draws more than the 1 amp the splitter could provide it might cause problems. Also, at that point if you're buying more to get this to work, it would make sense to just buy a 802.3at PoE+ injector (https://store.ui.com/us/en/collections/uisp-accessory-tech-poe-surge-adapters/products/poe-48) and keep the project cleaner.